# stream processing and batch processing

Tags: apache-spark, stream, apache-flink, processing, pipeline

Since the latency with batch processing generates when accumulating a specific number of data, can I regard batch processing with the "size of one" as stream processing? Or there's other difference when operators do calculations?

For example, if I set the batch size of a spark-based program to 1, can I make its latency as low as flink?

One of my thinking is as below:
For stream processing, one data flows from former operator to latter one if processed, but for batch process, only after all the operator finish processing a data can it accept another data.
It seems the pipeline in stream processing counts for the acceleration.

Am I right in my explantion? If wrong, what's the appropriate explanation to my question.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: there are quite a lot of reasons why you should help your program and tell it explicitly wether you want a bounded(batch) or unbounded(stream) computation.

Your thinking is good in theory, but that's not how it works in practice: batch vs stream setting is being asked explicitly from the programmer. The runtime won't infer it from the batch size (or batch delay) you set. At least that's how Flink works.

Furthermore, the batch vs stream divide goes much deeper: batch shouldn't care much about time.

Let's say you increase the batch size to be the whole dataset size. Only in that case Flink will be able to apply performance optimization passes over your plan. For example: in streaming mode `JOIN`s need to keep both sides in memory in case a match appears on the other side. In batching mode, Flink knows both sides are fixed-size, it can materialize first the smallest side and only keep that in memory while it queries it with the other side. Thus Flinks need less memory for batching, and it uses CPU caches better (which makes for a faster processing).

Also streaming has to maintain watermarks (special row metadata to help with correlating the right rows together time-wise, persisting coherent set of rows together, etc), while batch doesn't care about them. That's overhead.

If you're up for it you can peruse the Flink source code, and compare the [Batch](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/a251888dce5aab3f76d066241d84061b87658bb3/flink-table/flink-table-planner/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/table/planner/plan/rules/FlinkBatchRuleSets.scala) vs [Stream](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/a251888dce5aab3f76d066241d84061b87658bb3/flink-table/flink-table-planner/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/table/planner/plan/rules/FlinkStreamRuleSets.scala) SQL optimization rules. You'll see that stream has to deal with watermarks (`FlinkLogicalWatermarkAssigner`) when batch does not, it has to expand temporal tables fully (`LogicalCorrelateToJoinFromTemporalTableRule`). Batch also can sort rows and do sort-merge-joins (`BatchPhysicalSortMergeJoinRule`). Stream has to incrementally process aggregates (`IncrementalAggregateRule`) when batch can do them locally at the data source (`PushLocalHashAggIntoScanRule`), etc. Each difference between these two files is either a thing one side has to specifically do because of its (batch vs stream) nature, or an optimization pass that is allowed by its (batch vs stream) nature.

If you would like to know more about this topic and it's numerous subtleties, you can also read the [Flink Blog posts](https://flink.apache.org/blog/), [Flink Documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/overview/), [Flink Improvement Proposals](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Flink+Improvement+Proposals)